# Retrieve data from API of different source systems using C#

Tags: c#, api, soap

I am here for your help. First time handling a task about the API, SAP/SOAP, Web services. Sorry, as this is a long post. Let me explain the workflow.

1. XYZ Server calls the API Application (which I need to develop) to obtain the UserIDs.
2. These UserIDs will be used to retrieve the data from API of 3 different source systems (ABC, PGS, KGT). ABC and PGS are using RestAPI while the KGT is using SOAP.
3. The retrieved data will be stored in the In-Memory.
4. The API Application will insert all the APIs in the In-Memory to the XYZ server.

[image: Workflow image]

Here's my question:

1. Is it possible to use only the VS Code for the development?
2. There's no database provided. How am I able to store the retrieved data into the memory?
3. Based on the workflow, is it possible to develop the API application in just a week? Given that I am only a newbie?

I just need your ideas on how I am going to start the development. Currently, I already have a method to get the user ID and to insert the data back into the XYZ server.

Note: The API Application is a non-UI. It serves or acts as a middleman, to transfer data from other systems to XYZ system.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: What SAP software are you talking about? SAP has published hundreds (thousands?) of software. SAP is 3rd software company in the world.

Comment: It should be SOAP like an XML file format.

Comment: SOAP is Web standards for Web Services, unrelated to SAP company. I guess there's nothing in the question or answer related to SAP software (except that you use SOAP protocol for our information).

Comment: Q1: since this is tagged 'C#', yes. Q2: I guess an [InMemory database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) is what is meant. There are different ones, EF core is just an example. Q3: I doubt it, but who knows ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps but I will try to help you.
First, I think it i totally possible to only use VS Code as you are just coding an API.
Second, have you though about having an in-memory database like Redis?
Third, I think it depends. It is possible to do that in a week at least for more experienced people, but as a "newbie" as you said, I think maybe some more time might be needed.
Hope it helps ^^